# Ionic Firebase Google Login

Tags: firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2, google-signin

I'm new at App Developing, but I am building an app with a Google Login connected to my Firebase.
I can connect and show the user id with success but I want to go to another page (HomePage) when success login.

```
import { HomePage } from "../home/home";
import { RegisterPage } from "../register/register";

import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { GooglePlus } from "@ionic-native/google-plus";
import { Platform } from "ionic-angular";



@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: "page-login",
  templateUrl: "login.html"
})
export class LoginPage {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(
    public nav: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public forgotCtrl: AlertController,
    public menu: MenuController,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private gplus: GooglePlus,
    private router: Router,
    private platform: Platform
  ) {
    this.menu.swipeEnable(false);
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState;
  }
    async nativeGoogleLogin(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const gplusUser = await this.gplus.login({
        webClientId:
          "MyClientWebAPI",
        offline: true,
        scopes: "profile email"
      });

      return await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)
//Here is where i try to inject the router.
        .then(success => {
          this.router.navigate(["HomePage"]);
        })
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
 googleLogin() {
    if (this.platform.is("cordova")) {
      this.nativeGoogleLogin();
    } else {
      this.webGoogleLogin();
    }
  }
```

I tried to inject some code in the auth by using then(success =>....) but I can't get it to work.

Can anyone help with the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 return await this.afAuth.auth
        .signInWithCredential(
          firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(gplusUser.idToken)
        )
        .then(data => {
          this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

async webGoogleLogin(): Promise<void> {
        try {
          const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
          const credential = await this.afAuth.auth
            .signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then(data => {
              this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
            });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this:

```js
 async loginUser() {
    this.user.email = this.myForm.value.email;
    this.user.password = this.myForm.value.password;
    this.presentLoading();
    try {
      this.authService
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.user)
        .then(data => {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(ListaPage);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log("error");
        });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

and in AuthService you can insert the Google Login Logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It help me solve my problem by adding .then(data => { this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);     after the signin provider. I had some problems with your code... .loading.dismiss was not reconized... do i have to add it to my module?

Comment: Sorry, I added a loading for wait the promise response you need delete this.loadings code